# redirect to Paypal but failed

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, paypal, opera, microsoft-edge

I used a script to redirect to Paypal link, it worked on firefox and edge, but failed on chrome and opera, it reported error

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=myemail@mydomain.com&undefined_quantity=1&custom=&item_name=MyProductName&amount=29.95&currency_code=USD" on this server.
Reference #18.e5690317.1465451141.231a6f6c
```

I even try to access 
http://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=myemail@mydomain.com

directly from web browser, same situation(Firefox edge worked correctly but chrome and opera reported similar error above)

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=myemail@mydomain.com" on this server.
Reference #18.e5690317.1465451528.232110b2
```

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your url work just fine. However, this other way should work as well. Please try it:

http://www.paypal.com/xclick?business=myemail@mydomain.com

Please notice the "?" symbol after xclick.